# What is the css class for "tooltip" in flotr2?

Tags: javascript, flotr2

I have several graphs, and when I hover over dots I make use of **"trackformatter"** function to display data. Problem is that the z-index of the tooltip is to low, so it appears behind other graphs. And I can't seem to find the css class of it so that I can set its z-index to a high number. Does anyone of you guys know what class this tooltip is making use of in the graph library flotr2?

[image]

```
trackFormatter: function(obj) {
   var test = ResultPresenter.getTooltip(data, result, "test");
   return test;//What css class is used here?
},
```

http://humblesoftware.com/flotr2/index#!mouse-drag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. It user the class

`class="flotr-mouse-value"` in file flotr2.js

```
S_MOUSETRACK = 'z-index:1000;opacity:0.7;background-color:#000;color:#fff;position:absolute;padding:2px 8px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;white-space:nowrap;'
```

I still can't fix the z-index issue though, only change the other values.

Comment: I added the `flotr-mouse-value` to my own stylesheet with a `z-index` value of 9999, and this resolved the issue for me. My stylesheet has a higher specificity since it's applied after the flot2 stylesheet.